# Let end users edit a pdf in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I'm trying to find a way to let the client of a website I'm working on (specifically an administrator) edit the content of a pdf file. For example, if the client decides that they want to change the wording on a pdf (but not the format), they can click a button or something and make the changes they need to without asking me to do it. Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out The Ruby Toolbox page for report generation, specifically PDF_generation. There's a couple of different options with reviews and documentation.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pdf_generation